# Problemas no SELECT com postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Estou fazendo uma migração de mysql para postgres, mas está acontecendo um erro, não muita experiência com postgres:

SELECT

```
SELECT m.* , (SELECT c.id 
                FROM corridas c 
                WHERE c.motoqueiro = m.id 
                AND (c.status = 0 OR c.status = 1)) as total 
FROM motoqueiros m 
WHERE now() - INTERVAL '17888 SECONDS' <= data_update 
AND count(total) = 0;
```

Mensagem de erro:

> ERROR:  column "total" does not exist
>   LINE 2: ...INTERVAL '17888 SECONDS' <= data_update AND count(total) = 0
>                                                                ^
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: column "total" does not exist
>   SQL state: 42703
>   Character: 198

alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Conseguiu corrigir o erro com a resposta?

Comment: @GOKUSSJ4 ainda não brother!

Comment: Rubens, você poderia postar as tabelas `corridas` e `motoqueiros` com dados de exemplo e o que você espera como resultado dessa consulta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu erro é porque você quer usar uma colunar que não existe no seu contexto(tabela) , ou seja, a coluna total não existe ainda, você esta renomeando ela a partir do seu *sub select*, se você quiser usar ela assim terá que fazer um sub select ou usar o seu select no lugar desta coluna.

```
SELECT m.* , (SELECT c.id 
                FROM corridas c 
                WHERE c.motoqueiro = m.id 
                AND (c.status = 0 OR c.status = 1)) as total 
FROM motoqueiros m 
WHERE now() - INTERVAL '17888 SECONDS' <= data_update 
AND (SELECT count(c.id)
                FROM corridas c 
                WHERE c.motoqueiro = m.id 
                AND (c.status = 0 OR c.status = 1) = 0;
```

Ou fazer o sub select

```
select * from 
(
    SELECT m.* , (SELECT count(c.id) 
                    FROM corridas c 
                    WHERE c.motoqueiro = m.id 
                    AND (c.status = 0 OR c.status = 1)) as total 
    FROM motoqueiros m 
    WHERE now() - INTERVAL '17888 SECONDS' <= data_update 

)sub
where sub.total = 0;
```

Comment: a primeira deu o erro: ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
LINE 7: AND count((SELECT c.id 
            ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
SQL state: 42803
Character: 245

, já a segunda deu erro: ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
LINE 11: where count(sub.total) = 0;
               ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
SQL state: 42803
Character: 295

Comment: @RubensVentura,  Esse total é o total do select interno certo, acho que o seu count tem que ser nesse select . logo ...` m.* , (SELECT count(c.id), e depois remover do where sub.total = 0;`

Comment: deu certo brother!

Answer (score -1):

Tive o mesmo problema na versão 4.30, e descobri que os nomes das colunas precisam estar com aspas duplas.

Segue meu exemplo:

```
SELECT round (avg (f.salario_hora)), e.estado 
FROM "Cap16"."TB_FUNC" f, "Cap16"."TB_ENDERECO" e
WHERE f."ID" = e."id_func"
GROUP BY e."estado"
```